# How to delete last two columns from multiple files - code doesn't work

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to deletes last 2 columns from multiple files in a directory.
This code is close to what I need, but It just deletes last column(including HEADER7). It also deletes HEADER6 but, all the data from column 6 stay untouched.
Last column contains file names of every file.
Files are comma-delimited.

```
$InputFolder = '.\'
$OutputFolder = '.\'


Get-ChildItem $InputFolder -Filter *.* |
where {-not $_.psiscontainer} |
foreach {
$FileName = $_.Name
$BaseName = $_.Basename
$data = Get-Content $_ -ReadCount 0
$($data[0]) -replace  ",HEADER6",'' -replace ",HEADER7",'' | Set-Content $OutputFolder\$FileName 
$data[1..($data.Length -1)] -replace ",$HEADER6",'' -replace ",$BaseName",'' | Add-Content $OutputFolder\$FileName
 }
```

File sample

```
HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3,HEADER4,HEADER5,HEADER6,HEADER7
22.1,34.02,12.00,23.44,123.33,12.34,FILE1
25.1,30.22,12.55,21.40,13.03,15.31,FILE1
15.51,10.24,11.54,11.50,12.13,17.14,FILE1
```

.
.
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is any faster:

```
$InputFolder = '.\'
$OutputFolder = '.\'


Get-ChildItem $InputFolder -Filter *.* |
where {-not $_.psiscontainer} |
foreach {
$FileName = $_.Name
(Get-Content $_ -ReadCount 0 ) -replace ',[^,]+,[^,]+$' |
Set-Content $OutputFolder\$FileName 
 }
```

Comment: Wow your code works just perfect and is very fast too. I tested your code with other code posted below on a sample of 3500 files and the result is  1:35 vs 3:00 min. Very impressive. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!  Using -replace as an array operator vs doing a Foreach through the file lines probably accounts for most of the performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could try string-manipulation. It should be faster than `import-/export-csv` if you have large files:

```
Get-ChildItem $InputFolder -Filter *.* |
Where-Object {-not $_.psiscontainer} |
ForEach-Object {
    $FileName = $_.Name
    $text = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($_.FullName)
    $modifiedtext = foreach($line in $text) {
        $line -replace '(?<=\S*?,\S*?,\S*?,\S*?,\S*?),.*'
    }

    $modifiedtext | Set-Content $OutputFolder\$FileName
    #The line below might be even faster.
    #[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines(((Resolve-Path $OutputFolder\$FileName).Path), $modifiedtext)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.It is working but I have two concerns about your code.1 I have a thousands of files in a directory.It took almost 6 minutes to your code to finish a job.The code I posted is more than 60% faster. Only problem with my code is that it only deletes last column and header of the second last column(it doesn't delete actual data from the second last column)    2.I would like to rewrite original files into the same directory. Do you have any suggestion what's wrong with my code? Thank you.

Comment: The problem with your code is that you're trying to replace `,$header6` in every line. What is `$header6`? It's not defined. Also, the data is not the same in every line in the column, so you can't try to replace it with a static value. Try updated answer to see if performance is improved.

Comment: Thank you, your code works very well.Exactly how I need. Only problem is that it is still much slower than mjolinor's code. I tested both codes on a sample of 3500 files and the other code was much faster. 1:35 vs 3:00 min.But anyway, for smaller number of files your code can be used without problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could import the CSV, select the columns you want to keep and export directly

```
Import-Csv c:\TEMP\test.csv | Select-Object -property HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3,HEADER4,HEADER5 | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation c:\temp\test2.csv
```